# Google Play Games Service API how to synchronize a player's game data across multiple devices?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, android-snapshot

The [Google Play Saved Games Developer site](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) mentions "The Saved Games service makes it possible to synchronize a player's game data across multiple devices." But does not give any examples, instruction or even an approach to accomplish this. I'm familiar with implementing snapshots to save and load app data to/from snapshots, but not how to keep device snapshots/data in sync acrosss devices. So what is the approach to leverage the Google Saved Games API to sync a players Game Data across devices? An example of how someone has accomplished this would be even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) you gave that, "*To learn how to implement saved games for your platform, see [Client implementations](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames#client_implementations).*"

You may check this [Adding Saved Games to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) guide that shows you how to use the Saved Games API in an Android application.

To retrieve all saved games for the currently signed-in player, call the [`load()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots.html#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, boolean)) method.

Your game can also retrieve a specific saved game through the player's UI selection, as described in [Displaying Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames#displaying_saved_game). The returned saved game is represented as a [`Snapshot`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshot.html), which your game can then open to read its content and metadata.

Comment: I've already implemented all of the above in my app. Saving/Loading/Opening snapshots. My question is in regards in the approach to keeping the same game progress synchronized across multiple devices. Do I have to force the user to load the snapshot every time they open the app? If the app is sitting in memory on a second device, how do I force that to refresh the data when they open the app?